# What is the name of the chord contains the notes Ab, C, D and G?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, jazz

In the key of Bb major I came across a chord that contained the notes Ab, C, D and G.

What chord could this be?

Answer (score 12):

This is an Ab major 7 flat 5 (Abmaj7(b5)) chord (if you hear Ab as its root). Many people would call it an Abmaj7(#11), because the b5 and the #11 are enharmonically the same note, and if you have a #11 you almost never have the perfect fifth in the chord anyway.

I often use this voicing (from low to high): `Ab G C D`

In the key of Bb major, this chord can function as a subdominant chord; it is borrowed from the mixolydian mode (where the 7 becomes a b7).

However, if Ab is not the root, then there are several other interpretations. It can be used as a Gsus4(b9), which gives a phrygian sound. It could also be used as an incomplete half-diminished chord: Dm7(b5,add 11) (without the 3rd).

If the root is left out (i.e. implied, or played by another instrument), then this chord can function as:

- Bb13
- E7(#5,#9)
- Fm6/9

You see, there's plenty of possibilities. The real question is: what do you *hear*?

Comment: Just a note on the spelling... If you use the flat5 interpretation then "D" should actually be called E-double-flat (Ebb). It's the same location on most instruments, but it is notionally different.